# PHP: Creating a simple Captcha

Tags: php, gd

I have created a simple captcha generator, but won't show captcha-image :

**index.php :**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['captcha'] = rand(1000, 9999);
?>

<img src="generator.inc.php" />
```

**generator.inc.php :**

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$text = $_SESSION['captcha'];

$font_size = 30;
$image_width = 160;
$image_height = 50;

$image = imagecreate($image_width, $image_height);

imagecolorallocate($image, 200, 200, 200);

$font_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 20 , 20 , 20);

imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 15, 30, $font_color, 'BYekan.ttf', $text);

imagejpeg($image);
?>
```

Please tell me what am i doing wrong?

**P.S :**

I'm using Lamp server on Linux.

Comment: What happens when you view the image? Also, don't use a custom-made captcha in production code. There's a good chance that it'll be trivial to break.

Comment: @Blender Image won't show. You can see shot [here](http://up.vbiran.ir/uploads/137561490836539_gd1.png).

Comment: how you can access BYekan.ttf ? I mean where is the font file ?

Comment: @Blender When implemented properly, I doubt that, especially since there is less benefit for malicious hackers to break it if it's not widely used.

Comment: @JanithChinthana BYekan is along index.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably [GD library](http://libgd.bitbucket.org/) is not installed.

Also check in `php.ini` and make sure GD line be uncommented.

Answer (score 0):

I remove the `header` function call in your script and found an error that you have not defined the `$image_height` variable. In your script, you duplicate the `$image_width` assignment.

Comment: Can you remove the `header` function and let me know what appear in the screen when your navigate to the `generator.inc.php` file from the browser?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to try 2 things:

I have read and seen before that people suggest to place the content type `header('Content-type: image/jpeg');` just before the `imagejpeg($image);`. To back this up here is an article profing it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

My other suggestion would be to base64_encode the file. If `header('Content-type: image/jpeg');` produces an error suggestion "*header() must be called before any actual output is sent*" then base64_encode allows one to create an image with specifying the content type. Remove the header code and then add the following code when `imagejpeg($image);` is called.

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($image); //your code
$img = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($img).'" />';
```